# Trying to display queried user information using Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I have a template user profile that has a label. I've created a user and it's stored in my Parse backend in a "User" table. I'm trying to retrieve that information and display it on the user profile.

This is my function to retrieve the data from Parse:

```
    //stores the retrieved information from Parse
    var userInformation: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray() 

    //Label for the user name
     @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    //retrieves information from Parse
    func loadUserInformation() {

    var getUserInformation: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
    getUserInformation.whereKey("username", equalTo: //use the current user logged in)

    getUserInformation.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            for object:PFObject in objects as! [PFObject] {
                self.userInformation.addObject(object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First Question: How do I know which user is signed in, and how do I use that information in "equalTo" for "whereKey"?

Second Question: How do I then use the information retrieved, get the user's name (it's stored in parse as "Full_Name" at index 9), and display that information in the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:
In Parse, you get the current user by simply calling `PFUser.currentUser()`, which returns a PFUser. Then you have the whole information fetched, e.g. try:

```
if let user = PFUser.currentUser()
{
    println(user.username) // etc.
}
```

Second question:
Simply call within the `if let user...`-block:

```
self.userNameLabel.text = user["Full_Name"]
```

To learn more about Parse Users in iOS, visit: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users

Answer (score 0):

you can receive the current user by using the code

```
var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
```

from this you'll be able to find the current username.

ie.

```
var currentUserName = PFUser.currentUser()?.username!
```

if you only have one username per person you should be able to use

```
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        var firstName = object!["FirstName"] as! String
    }
```